# How to set a maximum number of days to select using v-calendar range in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli, vcalendar

Using vuejs [vcalendar range](https://vcalendar.io/datepicker.html#date-ranges) , I want to limit the number of days the user can select. Do you know it there is some kind of a "maxDays" option?
I have also tried to create a method where when the range is bigger than a certain number of days, the end date is modified to fit the maximum range. The issue here that I found was that the calendar wasnt updating, even if the date object was.

So lets say I have in my template the following calendar:

`<v-date-picker v-model="range" is-range />`

Where "range" is:

```
data() {
    return {
      range: {
        start: new Date(),
        end: new Date(),
      },
    };
  }
```

I have a method that checks if the range is valid. And if it is not valid (i.e. when it is too big), the end date is modified:

```
if (!this.validRange) {
        let startDate = this.range.start;
        let endDate = new Date();
        endDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 6);
        this.$set(this.range, "end", endDate);
      }
```

And as I said, the value range.end changes properly, but the calendar still shows the same range without updating the range.end value.

Is there a way I can fix this?
And I know other libraries can do those kind of thigs, I just want to know if it is possible with v-calendar.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Julien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lhd9eov4/

HTML:

```
<div id='app'>
  <v-date-picker
          v-model="range"
          is-range
          @input="handleInput()"
        />
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      range: {
        start: new Date(),
        end: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1),
      }
  }},
  
  methods:{
        handleInput(){
        this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.range = {
          start: this.range.start,
          end: new Date().setDate(this.range.start.getDate() + 6),
          };
        });
      }
    }
})
```

The range seems reactive when you create a new object. Listening to the input event and then updating the range (in another DOM update cycle) seems to do the job.

Comment: Hey! 
Thanks for answering. It indeed did the trick to limit the number of days selected. I just had to modify a little bit your code so that if the range selected was smaller than 6 days, this.range.end would keep the same value.

Comment: @JulienRobitaille, Consider posting your modified code. Thx.